# Where is freeglut.a in cygwin?

Tags: c, cygwin, gnu, freeglut

I'm trying to implement a little OpenGL renderer in VSCode with cygwin's gcc, using freeglut as windowing system and I'm failing linking against freeglut. I have no clue what the library is called, according to [what I found on the web](https://www.transmissionzero.co.uk/computing/using-glut-with-mingw/), I should be able to link with `-lfreeglut`, but this gives me a the following:

> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lfreeglut
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

I searched my cygwin folder for "glut" and found many things, but no library. Funny enough the headers are present. Btw, I installed the freeglut package (mingw64-x86_64-freeglut v 2.8.1-1) with cygwin's package installer. Also, I'm completely unexperienced in GNU systems, so the answer may be quite straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

I think was never `-lfreeglut` but always `-lglut`

Try compiling with the normal GLUT library package

```
libglut-devel: OpenGL Utility Toolkit library
```

it includes the shared library

```
usr/lib/libglut.dll.a
```

both headers

```
usr/include/GL/freeglut.h
usr/include/GL/freeglut_ext.h
usr/include/GL/freeglut_std.h
usr/include/GL/freeglut_ucall.h
usr/include/GL/glut.h
```

In general you can use cygcheck for finding the needed package.

```
$ cygcheck -p libglut.dll.a
Found 5 matches for libglut.dll.a
libglut-devel-2.8.1-1 - libglut-devel: OpenGL Utility Toolkit librar
y (installed binaries and support files)
libglut-devel-3.0.0-1 - libglut-devel: OpenGL Utility Toolkit librar
y
libglut-devel-3.2.1-1 - libglut-devel: OpenGL Utility Toolkit librar
y
...
```